# What is Alfresco Content Services?

Tags: database-design, alfresco, dynamic-sql, dynamic-data, alfresco-enterprise

(I've no experience in web programming & design)

I've read their website and watched videos, but am still confused on what the program actually is, who uses it and how it can be used?

I'm under the impression it can be used for dynamic sites like Databases?

Answer (score 3):

Alfresco Content Services is a java/spring based product which is designed to manage content of enterprise (mainly documents). It manages documents with all its metadata and controls its access to users.
Apart from this APS (Alfresco Process Services) which supports business process management. So overall Alfresco is the combination of both content management and BPM.
for more you can visit this [Alfresco Documentation - Alfresco overview](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/system-about-community.html).

Comment: Thank you. So its not really a program/engine? Its more of a interface? Is this different from Alfresco One? Also can this be implemented to control other databases?

Comment: Earlier, ACS was known as ECM (Enterprise Content Management) , as it is quiet general , alfresco has changed it to ACS. But its not different than Alfresco One. Alfresco One (commercial version of Alfresco Community) comprises of ACS and APS.

Comment: OK so basically this connects things together & manages it behind the scenes, rather than an interface that all staff would work from? This could be used in website optimization?

Comment: No, it does not have to do anything with website optimisation. Enterprises like R&D dept in pharmaceuticals , legal dept as well as any enterprise which has to deal with lots of docs, and it is quiet difficult for them to deal with those docs. So in that case they want to manage their docs digitally(scanned ) and they can extract info from docs and control the access of docs based on user-role wise.